# Scraping Data from Website using vba doesn´t work

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping, mshtml

I want to create a list of player names scraping a website. The Internet Explorer starts but I get an run time error "438" - Object does not support this property or method.

Structure of webpage

[image: Structure of webpage]

My coding is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kickbase()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLPlayers As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLPlayer As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim HTMLfirstName As Object
Dim firstName As String


IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://play.kickbase.com/transfermarkt/kaufen"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLPlayers = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("players")

For i = 0 To HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassName("firstName").Length - 1

Set HTMLfirstName = HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassName("firstName")

   If Not HTMLfirstName Is Nothing Then
    firstName = Trim(HTMLfirstName.innerText)
    
   Else
     firstName = "no_value"
   End If

Debug.Print firstName

Next i

End Sub
```

I have activated the following libraries:
[image]

Comment: There's no method called `getElementsByTagclassname`... its `getElementsByClassName` which you did use in the line just above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I corrected my typing error, but the issue still persists.

Comment: `HTMLPlayers` is a collection of elements but you did not refer to a specific element in your `For` loop. E.g. `HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassname("firstName")` fyi update your question with the edited code to make it easier for people to help you

Comment: I edited the code above with your feedback. Afterwards I get a new error "runtime error 48 - error while loading a DLL". It seems that there is somehting not correct with my libraries. I have acutally selected under references the following libraries: Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Comment: I think is because you use `For each` loop with elementcollection object, I remember there's some problem with it. Try using `For` loop instead, something like `For i = 0 to HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassname("firstName").Length - 1`. It might be easier if you make another variable to hold `firstName` collection and do the loop with that instead. @Poseidon

Comment: That was a good hint. I have updated the coding again. Now I can select all Names to my html object. I can see the names are in the "inner text". But there is an error in   `firstName = Trim(HTMLfirstName.innerText)`. I cant print the innertext.

Comment: Again, `HTMLfirstName` is a **collection** of elements so you must refer to a specific element to access its property. Try `firstName = Trim(HTMLfirstName(0).innerText)`. I'm assuming you want the first element in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to test the website on my own, the code below might not be the best way to do it but it should work:

```
Sub Kickbase()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLPlayers As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstName As String
        
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://play.kickbase.com/transfermarkt/kaufen"
    
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
    Set HTMLPlayers = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("playerName")
            
    For i = 0 To HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassName("firstName").Length - 1
        
        firstName = Trim$(HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassName("firstName")(i).innerText)
        If firstName = vbNullString Then firstName = "no_value"
            
        Debug.Print firstName
    Next i
    
    '=== Optional depending on your use case, remember to close IE or else it will remain there ===
    'IE.Quit
    'Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```